# Autopy Error. toggle(down, button=LEFT_BUTTON) -> None

Tags: python, module, mouse, python-idle, mousemove

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#68>", line 1, in <module>
    mouse.toggle(down, button=LEFT_BUTTON)
NameError: name 'down' is not defined
```

And this shows up on Help:
`toggle(down, button=LEFT_BUTTON)` -> None

So, yes. I can't seem to make mouse.click and mouse.toggle to work. `mouse.get_pos()` and `mouse.smooth_move() and mouse.move()` works just fine. Any ideas on what the problem here is?

Comment: From the API: "Holds down or releases the given mouse button in the current position. button can be LEFT_BUTTON, RIGHT_BUTTON, or CENTER_BUTTON. If no button is given, the left button is defaulted to."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mouse.toggle(down, button=LEFT_BUTTON) is not the proper use of autopy.mouse

mouse.toggle(True, button=LEFT_BUTTON) or mouse.toggle(False, button=LEFT_BUTTON) are the correct usage